# Zend Project gives 404

Tags: php, zend-framework, web, http-status-code-404

I am following this [tutorial](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/) and i am running into some trouble. The application is being hosted by networksolutions with shared hosting. When I try to access one of the newly created actions i get a 404 message.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I used the suggested htaccess settings for my public directory but still no luck. What could the problem be?

Comment: are you allowed to use .htaccess in your hosting environment?

Comment: have you enabled apache rewrite module ? (a2enmod rewrite)

Comment: im quite sure the htaccess works because putting invalid code into it gives a 500. Im not sure how i would enable or even check the rewrite module? I only have access to the dashboard on network solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can check mod_rewrite enabled or disabled by:

```
in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules());
```

Also, how are you accessing your files?
ideally, it is : example.com//
Made sure that you have "views/scripts//" ?